# How to link webform to Bronto Database list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, bronto

I have an old Html form already hooked up to Bronto already:

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup"><form id="lunar-form"><input name="fid" type="hidden" value="3yuzy87x8gjdf73zq9p6lav86dfdw" />
<input name="sid" type="hidden" value="01c3cd9e15ec122d6bada9aeba8dbe44" />
<input name="delid" type="hidden" value="" />
<input name="subid" type="hidden" value="" />
<input name="td" type="hidden" value="" />
<input name="formtype" type="hidden" value="addcontact" />
<input id="field_361909" class="hidden field" name="67765[361909]" type="hidden" value="Weekly" />
<input id="field_361796" class="hidden field" name="67746[361796]" type="hidden" value="Hair Shaman Lunar" />
<script type="text/javascript">
 var fieldMaps = {};
 </script>
<fieldset id="popupfieldset">
<div class="mc-field-group-email">

<input id="mce-EMAIL" class="text field fb-email" title="7 characters minimum" autocomplete="off" name="74662" pattern=".{7,}" required="" type="email" value="" placeholder="Email" />
```

i want to add another input for first name, how do I make sure it connects to the bronto database correctly?